# Need to vizualize vSphere stats into an executive dashboard

Tags: monitoring, dashboard

We are trying to find a (preferable free) tool to pull and visualize vHost/network data from vSphere in a form of an easy-to-read executive dashboard with an option to expand the presented readings/status to a more granular output, if needed. I am fairly new to this problematic and need an educated kick into the right direction. So far I have come across various more or less sophisticated (and in many cases free, too) monitoring tools, however optimally we need to make the best use of the information already available from within vSphere and visualize it. Hopefully this is not too ambiguous. Many thanks!